# Get twilio account usage grouped by subaccount

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

Any one know how to get the account usage grouped by subaccounts?

```
var records = RecordResource.Read(
            category: RecordResource.CategoryEnum.Sms,
            startDate: DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30),
            endDate: DateTime.Today);
```

^Will give me only individual or the master account, but I need it broken down.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To get the usage for a subaccount, you can make the same request, you just need to add the subaccount sid.

```
var records = RecordResource.Read(
            SUBACCOUNT_SID_GOES_HERE,
            category: RecordResource.CategoryEnum.Sms,
            startDate: DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30),
            endDate: DateTime.Today);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of it for every subaccount under the master, would I need to get all the accounts then make a call for each? Doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: That is correct. If you want the usage for each of your subaccounts you will need to make an API call for each of them. You should be able to solve this with a loop though.

Comment: The inability to get total price of all subaccounts in a single request is a death knell. We have over 60 subaccounts. It takes minutes to request each one individually.

Comment: @WorksforaLiving I would likely run that as a background job on a schedule so you have your own cache of the data.